# Get UserId from a list of Users for a Lambda Function (AWS)

Tags: python, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Im trying to write a Lambda function in AWS that runs once for each existing User.
It needs to count how many Instances a user has running(I already have something that tags each instance with the UserId of its creator).
So I was trying to write a filter that gets all running Instances of user and then counts them.
The problem is: I somehow can´t manage to get the UserId from a user after I got a list of all Users.
Currently it looks like this:

```
users = client.list_users()

for user in users:
    #here is where I dont know how to get the UserId i´ve tried things like:
    #userId=user.UserId or userId=user['UserId'] and other things but I just cant get it to work

    instancefilters = [{
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name',
            'Values': ['running']
            },
        {
            'Name': 'PrincipalId',
            'Values': [userId]
            }
        }
    ]
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=instancefilters)

    RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]
```

I hope someone can help me I feel like there should be a really easy solution to this but I somehow cant find it

Edit: Im using Boto3 for this. Boto3´s client.list_users() returns a dict, with a list of Users with a dict of their data, like this:

```
{
'Users': [
    {
        'Path': 'string',
        'UserName': 'string',
        'UserId': 'string',
        'Arn': 'string',
        'CreateDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
        'PasswordLastUsed': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
        'PermissionsBoundary': {
            'PermissionsBoundaryType': 'PermissionsBoundaryPolicy',
            'PermissionsBoundaryArn': 'string'
        },
        'Tags': [
            {
                'Key': 'string',
                'Value': 'string'
            },
        ]
    },
],
'IsTruncated': True|False,
'Marker': 'string'
```

}

Comment: what users are you talking about ?  Your app ?  IAM users ? What is `client.list_users()` ?  It is very difficult to answer your question without more context.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help to rephrase your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is several errors here, although I am not sure which `key` you are giving when you tag the instances, I will assume the `Owner` tag.

```
users = client.list_users()

for user in users.get('Users', [{}]):
    instancefilters = [
        {
            'Name': 'instance-state-name',
            'Values': ['running']
            },
        {
            'Name': 'tag:Owner',
            'Values': [user.get('UserId')]
            }
    ]

    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=instancefilters)

    RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]
```

Comment: This gives me the error:  *'Values': [user.get('UserId')]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'*
Sorry im still getting abit confused with the nested dict/lists

Comment: works fine for me, did you copy over this code or modify yours because your original instancefilters is not valid python

Comment: Oh yea I modified mine and didn´t notice the faulty parantheses at first, thanks!